# strip time using strftime in pandas column as series object

Tags: pandas, strptime

I have a pandas dataframe containing time in column 1 and field x, y and z in other columns of the form

df =                          0      1      2      3
0        2010-Feb-13/08:44:15.588 -2.524  0.071 -0.606
1        2010-Feb-13/08:44:15.588 -2.539  0.079 -0.523
2        2010-Feb-13/08:44:15.588 -2.526  0.064 -0.523
3        2010-Feb-13/08:44:15.588 -2.536  0.069 -0.496
4        2010-Feb-13/08:44:15.588 -2.539  0.079 -0.551

I want to convert to datetime the column corresponding to 0 and subsequently convert it to a numpy array of datetime containing time stripped to '%H:%M:%s'. When I use strptime I get attribute error that datetime object doesn't apply to series object.

Comment: Have you tried using [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you can't apply strftime directly to a Series. Because a Series may have many dtypes, not only the datetype one. It's as if I wanted to apply .lower() to a float value: it makes no sense here.

So you need to spectify to pandas that you want to apply strftime **to the values of the Series for which this function actually means something**. In other terms:

**Don't** `df.strftime('%H:%M:%s')`
**Do**      `df.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%s')`  *# the `dt` means "treat the content of the series as datetime objects"*

Comment: Thanks. I already tried this. But now wroking